# what is this error for? 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'round'

Tags: python

```
cm = int(input("Write height in Centimeters:"))
inches = 0.394*cm
feet = 0.0328*cm
print(("The length in inches",round(inches,2))).round(inches,2)
print(("The length in feet",round(feet,2))).round(feet,2)
```

this is the code

this code should convert cm in feet and inches but there is a error

Comment: You already have `round()` inside the print call.  Why do you have another `.round()` on the end?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cm = int(input("Write height in Centimeters:"))
inches = 0.394*cm
feet = 0.0328*cm
print(("The length in inches",round(inches,2)))
print(("The length in feet",round(feet,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'll first break down the error:**
A `NoneType` object is basically the `None` object in Python. You could consider it to be basically an object with no value. If you're getting this error, it means you're trying to use the `.round()` method on something that either returns `None`, or a `None` value.

**Now about your code:**
You use the `.round()` method on a `print()` function, which returns `None`. So instead you should remove that and just have something like this:

```py
print(("The length in inches",round(inches,2))) # Removed extra .round()
print(("The length in feet",round(feet,2)))
```

Full code:

```py
cm = int(input("Write height in Centimeters:"))
inches = 0.394*cm
feet = 0.0328*cm
print(("The length in inches",round(inches,2)))
print(("The length in feet",round(feet,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call a method called `round()` as a class method of `print`. Print is not an object but a function which returns `None`, so you are attempting to call `round()` on None. Remove the `.round(inches, 2)` and `.round(feet, 2)` and your code should run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

NoneType in Python is a data type that simply shows that an object has no value/has a value of None.

NoneType does't have a round attribute as error said.

in your code you are using round attribut in print statement:

print(("The length in inches",round(inches,2)))**.round(inches,2)**

that is why python give you error.

your code should be:

```
print(("The length in inches",round(inches,2)))
```